# Can't connect to my MariaDB database using an external website

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, synology, nas

i'm trying to make a Geometry Dash private server (I want to host it on my Synology NAS), but the URL is too long, so i'm making another website to connect to my database. I've got a file "connection.php" :

```
<?php
$servername = "X.X.X.X";
$port = 3307;
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";
?>
```

and getGJLevels.php :

```
<?php
//header
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
include "../lib/connection.php";
require_once "../lib/GJPCheck.php";
require_once "../lib/exploitPatch.php";
require_once "../lib/mainLib.php";
$gs = new mainLib();
require "../lib/generateHash.php";

//initializing variables
$lvlstring = ""; $userstring = ""; $songsstring = ""; $lvlsmultistring = []; $str = ""; $order = "uploadDate";
$orderenabled = true; $ordergauntlet = false;
$params = array("NOT unlisted = 1");
$morejoins = "";

if(!empty($_POST["gameVersion"])){
  $gameVersion = ExploitPatch::number($_POST["gameVersion"]);
}else{
  $gameVersion = 0;
}
if(!is_numeric($gameVersion)){
  exit("-1");
}
if($gameVersion == 20){
  $binaryVersion = ExploitPatch::number($_POST["binaryVersion"]);
  if($binaryVersion > 27){
    $gameVersion++;
  }
}
if(!empty($_POST["type"])){
  $type = ExploitPatch::number($_POST["type"]);
}else{
  $type = 0;
}
if(!empty($_POST["diff"])){
  $diff = ExploitPatch::numbercolon($_POST["diff"]);
}else{
  $diff = "-";
}


//ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS
if($gameVersion==0){
  $params[] = "levels.gameVersion <= 18";
}else{
  $params[] = "levels.gameVersion <= '$gameVersion'";
}
if(!empty($_POST["featured"]) AND $_POST["featured"]==1){
  $params[] = "starFeatured = 1";
}
if(!empty($_POST["original"]) AND $_POST["original"]==1){
  $params[] = "original = 0";
}
if(!empty($_POST["coins"]) AND $_POST["coins"]==1){
    $params[] = "starCoins = 1 AND NOT levels.coins = 0";
}
if(!empty($_POST["epic"]) AND $_POST["epic"]==1){
  $params[] = "starEpic = 1";
}
if(!empty($_POST["uncompleted"]) AND $_POST["uncompleted"]==1){
  $completedLevels = ExploitPatch::numbercolon($_POST["completedLevels"]);
  $params[] = "NOT levelID IN ($completedLevels)";
}
if(!empty($_POST["onlyCompleted"]) AND $_POST["onlyCompleted"]==1){
  $completedLevels = ExploitPatch::numbercolon($_POST["completedLevels"]);
  $params[] = "levelID IN ($completedLevels)";
}
if(!empty($_POST["song"])){
  if(empty($_POST["customSong"])){
    $song = ExploitPatch::number($_POST["song"]);
    $song = $song -1;
    $params[] = "audioTrack = '$song' AND songID = 0";
  }else{
    $song = ExploitPatch::number($_POST["song"]);
    $params[] = "songID = '$song'";
  }
}
if(!empty($_POST["twoPlayer"]) AND $_POST["twoPlayer"]==1){
  $params[] = "twoPlayer = 1";
}
if(!empty($_POST["star"])){
  $params[] = "NOT starStars = 0";
}
if(!empty($_POST["noStar"])){
  $params[] = "starStars = 0";
}
if(!empty($_POST["gauntlet"])){
  $ordergauntlet = true;
  $order = "starStars";
  $gauntlet = ExploitPatch::remove($_POST["gauntlet"]);
  $query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM gauntlets WHERE ID = :gauntlet");
  $query->execute([':gauntlet' => $gauntlet]);
  $actualgauntlet = $query->fetch();
  $str = $actualgauntlet["level1"].",".$actualgauntlet["level2"].",".$actualgauntlet["level3"].",".$actualgauntlet["level4"].",".$actualgauntlet["level5"];
  $params[] = "levelID IN ($str)";
  $type = -1;
}
if(!empty($_POST["len"])){
  $len = ExploitPatch::numbercolon($_POST["len"]);
}else{
  $len = "-";
}
if($len != "-" AND !empty($len)){
  $params[] = "levelLength IN ($len)";
}

//DIFFICULTY FILTERS
switch($diff){
  case -1:
    $params[] = "starDifficulty = '0'";
    break;
  case -3:
    $params[] = "starAuto = '1'";
    break;
  case -2:
    if(!empty($_POST["demonFilter"])){
      $demonFilter = ExploitPatch::number($_POST["demonFilter"]);
    }else{
      $demonFilter = 0;
    }
    $params[] = "starDemon = 1";
    switch($demonFilter){
      case 1:
        $params[] = "starDemonDiff = '3'";
        break;
      case 2:
        $params[] = "starDemonDiff = '4'";
        break;
      case 3:
        $params[] = "starDemonDiff = '0'";
        break;
      case 4:
        $params[] = "starDemonDiff = '5'";
        break;
      case 5:
        $params[] = "starDemonDiff = '6'";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    break;
  case "-";
    break;
  default:
    if($diff){
      $diff = str_replace(",", "0,", $diff) . "0";
      $params[] = "starDifficulty IN ($diff) AND starAuto = '0' AND starDemon = '0'";
    }
    break;
}
//TYPE DETECTION
//TODO: the 2 non-friend types that send GJP in 2.11
if(!empty($_POST["str"])){
  $str = ExploitPatch::remove($_POST["str"]);
}
if(isset($_POST["page"]) AND is_numeric($_POST["page"])){
  $offset = ExploitPatch::number($_POST["page"]) . "0";
}else{
  $offset = 0;
}
switch($type){
  case 0:
  case 15: //most liked, changed to 15 in GDW for whatever reason
    $order = "likes";
    if(!empty($str)){
      if(is_numeric($str)){
        $params = array("levelID = '$str'");
      }else{
        $params[] = "levelName LIKE '%$str%'";
      }
    }
    break;
  case 1:
    $order = "downloads";
    break;
  case 2:
    $order = "likes";
    break;
  case 3: //TRENDING
    $uploadDate = time() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $params[] = "uploadDate > $uploadDate ";
    $order = "likes";
    break;
  case 5:
    $params[] = "levels.userID = '$str'";
    break;
  case 6: //featured
  case 17: //featured GDW //TODO: make this list of daily levels
    $params[] = "NOT starFeatured = 0";
    $order = "rateDate DESC,uploadDate";
    break;
  case 16: //HALL OF FAME
    $params[] = "NOT starEpic = 0";
    $order = "rateDate DESC,uploadDate";
    break;
  case 7: //MAGIC
    $params[] = "objects > 9999";
    break;
  case 10: //MAP PACKS
  case 19: //unknown but same as map packs (on real GD type 10 has star rated filter and 19 doesn't)
    $order = false;
    $params[] = "levelID IN ($str)";
    break;
  case 11: //AWARDED
    $params[] = "NOT starStars = 0";
    $order = "rateDate DESC,uploadDate";
    break;
  case 12: //FOLLOWED
    $followed = ExploitPatch::numbercolon($_POST["followed"]);
    $params[] = "users.extID IN ($followed)";
    break;
  case 13: //FRIENDS
    $accountID = GJPCheck::getAccountIDOrDie();
    $peoplearray = $gs->getFriends($accountID);
    $whereor = implode(",", $peoplearray);
    $params[] = "users.extID IN ($whereor)";
    break;
  case 21: //DAILY SAFE
    $morejoins = "INNER JOIN dailyfeatures ON levels.levelID = dailyfeatures.levelID";
    $params[] = "dailyfeatures.type = 0";
    $order = "dailyfeatures.feaID";
    break;
  case 22: //WEEKLY SAFE
    $morejoins = "INNER JOIN dailyfeatures ON levels.levelID = dailyfeatures.levelID";
    $params[] = "dailyfeatures.type = 1";
    $order = "dailyfeatures.feaID";
    break;
  case 23: //EVENT SAFE (assumption)
    $morejoins = "INNER JOIN dailyfeatures ON levels.levelID = dailyfeatures.levelID";
    $params[] = "dailyfeatures.type = 2";
    $order = "dailyfeatures.feaID";
    break;
}
//ACTUAL QUERY EXECUTION
$querybase = "FROM levels LEFT JOIN songs ON levels.songID = songs.ID LEFT JOIN users ON levels.userID = users.userID $morejoins";
if(!empty($params)){
  $querybase .= " WHERE (" . implode(" ) AND ( ", $params) . ")";
}
$query = "SELECT levels.*, songs.ID, songs.name, songs.authorID, songs.authorName, songs.size, songs.isDisabled, songs.download, users.userName, users.extID $querybase $morejoins ";
if($order){
  if($ordergauntlet){
    $query .= "ORDER BY $order ASC";
  }else{
    $query .= "ORDER BY $order DESC";
  }
}
$query .= " LIMIT 10 OFFSET $offset";
//echo $query;
$countquery = "SELECT count(*) $querybase";
//echo $query;
$query = $db->prepare($query);
$query->execute();
//echo $countquery;
$countquery = $db->prepare($countquery);
$countquery->execute();
$totallvlcount = $countquery->fetchColumn();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
$levelcount = $query->rowCount();
foreach($result as &$level1) {
  if($level1["levelID"]!=""){
    $lvlsmultistring[] = ["levelID" => $level1["levelID"], "stars" => $level1["starStars"], 'coins' => $level1["starCoins"]];
    if(!empty($gauntlet)){
      $lvlstring .= "44:$gauntlet:";
    }
    $lvlstring .= "1:".$level1["levelID"].":2:".$level1["levelName"].":5:".$level1["levelVersion"].":6:".$level1["userID"].":8:10:9:".$level1["starDifficulty"].":10:".$level1["downloads"].":12:".$level1["audioTrack"].":13:".$level1["gameVersion"].":14:".$level1["likes"].":17:".$level1["starDemon"].":43:".$level1["starDemonDiff"].":25:".$level1["starAuto"].":18:".$level1["starStars"].":19:".$level1["starFeatured"].":42:".$level1["starEpic"].":45:".$level1["objects"].":3:".$level1["levelDesc"].":15:".$level1["levelLength"].":30:".$level1["original"].":31:".$level1['twoPlayer'].":37:".$level1["coins"].":38:".$level1["starCoins"].":39:".$level1["requestedStars"].":46:1:47:2:40:".$level1["isLDM"].":35:".$level1["songID"]."|";
    if($level1["songID"]!=0){
      $song = $gs->getSongString($level1);
      if($song){
        $songsstring .= $song . "~:~";
      }
    }
    $userstring .= $gs->getUserString($level1)."|";
  }
}
$lvlstring = substr($lvlstring, 0, -1);
$userstring = substr($userstring, 0, -1);
$songsstring = substr($songsstring, 0, -3);
echo $lvlstring."#".$userstring;
if($gameVersion > 18){
  echo "#".$songsstring;
}
echo "#".$totallvlcount.":".$offset.":10";
echo "#";
echo GenerateHash::genMulti($lvlsmultistring);
?>
```

But when it connect to the database, I get the errors

> "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"

and

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/runner/openedgdps/incl/levels/getGJLevels.php:252 Stack trace: #0 /home/runner/openedgdps/getGJLevels21.php(2): include() #1 {main} thrown in /home/runner/openedgdps/incl/levels/getGJLevels.php on line 252", can someone help me ?

Thanks

I tried all solutions i found on internet but nothing work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Firewall blocking connection?  Are you using the right port?   Normally it's 3306, but I'm assuming you changed the port#.   But the code "Exploitpatch" is a little iffy.

Comment: Looks like the root user is not allowed to connect. At least not without a password. Which is a good thing, actually, once you start thinking about that server being available on the internet ...

Comment: @arkascha "Connection refused" is at the network level, it's not dependent on authentication parameters. This is most likely due to a firewall blocking the MySQL port.

Comment: When you get an error connecting to the DB, the script should stop so you don't get worthless errors when you try to use the nonexistent connection.

Answer (score 0):

This typically indicates that your application is unable to establish a connection to the MariaDB database server. Maybe the server is not running, or the host or port is incorrect. Maybe there's a firewall blocking the connection or another network issue. Double-check your credentials (user/password). Check the docs and your configuration for the `bind-address` property (maybe it's restricting remote access). Check the MariaDB error log, probably located in `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` or `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.